# Changing the Emulation from 32-bit to 64 bit

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator

How Can i change the **32-bit** emulation to **64-bit**  in linux? How Can i force my AVD to change in 64 bit while running on 32bit machine
  I am newbie to android development.
         Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you machine is 32bit, you can not emulate 64bit. You need a 64bit machine to emulate a 64bit system.

Comment: I cant even force the emulator for 64 bit?

Comment: No, the arch is incompatible

Comment: Ohh,Well when i run the emulator in android studio it says that force your emulator to 64 bit. What does that mean?